# Отправка сообщения от сервера к клиенту через сокет

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, chat, client

В потоке `run()` строка: `clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(str.getBytes());`
не хочет отправлять клиенту сообщение. Сам сервер получает их от клиента, но, как я понимаю, в `getOutputStream()` ничего не передается. Вопрос почему?

Сервер

```
public class ServerMain extends  Thread {
    int num;
    public Thread run;
    Socket clientSocket;
    public List<ServerMain> clients2 = new ArrayList<>();
    int port;
    public ServerMain server;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        int i = 0;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(88);
            System.out.println("Server started on port " + 88);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                new ServerMain(i++, clientSocket);
                System.err.println("Client accepted " + i);
            } catch (IOException x) {
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public ServerMain(int num, Socket clientSocket) {
        this.num = num;
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        run();
    }

    public void run() {
        run = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                String str;
                while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Сообщение от клиента: " + str);
                    System.out.flush();
                    //добавляем клиента в коллекцию
                   // clients2.add(new ServerMain(num, clientSocket));         
                    System.out.println(str);
                    clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(str.getBytes());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Соединение прервалось с клиентом  ");
            }
        }, "run");
        run.start();
    }
}
```

Клиент (представлен только метод, читающий сокет)

```
public void send(String bytes) {
    send = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Невозможно получить поток вывода!");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
            try {
                writer.write(bytes + "\n");
                writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            read();
        }
    });
    send.start();
}
```

Comment: Код клиента тоже прикрепите к вопросу!

Comment: Если создавать поток для ввода/вывода для каждого клиента отдельно, то все работает. А надо, чтобы сервер нескольким клиентам отправлял сообщения. Реализовываю через коллекции. Сперва пробую просто отправить сообщение на сокет, чтобы клиент его прочел, но ничего не отправляется

Comment: Простите, но вы внутри главного класса создаете экземпляр этого же класса?

Comment: у вас довольно странно происходит чтение из сокета. больше похоже на запись.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот моё решение, возможно вам поможет, сравните с вашим кодом.

В данной программе сервер отправляет всем ранее подключенным клиентам сообщение о подключении нового клиента, все соединения с клиентом хранятся в коллекции.

Запускаете сервер и несколько раз клиент, и при запуске клиента будете видеть соответствующие сообщения у других клиентов и на сервере.

Пояснения:

- Сервер описан в отдельном классе.
- Метод `.accept();` надо запускать в отдельном потоке, чтобы не останавливать основной поток.
- Коллекцию соединений храним в статическом поле класса.
- Каждое соединение с клиентом работает в отдельном потоке.
- ObjectInputStream и ObjectOutputStream должны создаваться попарно, т.е. Если на стороне сервера вы создали первым ObjectInputStream, то на стороне клиента в первую очередь надо создать ObjectOutputStream.

Надеюсь, я вам помог...

**Сервер:**

*MainServer.java*

```
public class MainServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("server");
        Server server = new Server();
        server.startServer();
    }
}
```

*Server.java*

```
public class Server extends Thread{

    public static List<ClientConnection> connects = new ArrayList<>();

    private final int port = 4444;
    private ServerSocket serverSoket;

    public Server() {
        try {
            serverSoket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                ClientConnection clientConnection = new ClientConnection(serverSoket.accept());
                sendMessageAll("added: " + clientConnection.toString());
                Server.connects.add(clientConnection);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void startServer() {
        start();
    }

    public void stopServer() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void sendMessageAll(String msg) {
        for(ClientConnection client : connects) {
            client.send(msg);
        }
    }

}
```

*ClientConnection.java*

```
public class ClientConnection extends Thread{

    private Socket soket;

    private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;

    public ClientConnection(Socket soket) throws IOException {
        this.soket = soket;
        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(this.soket.getInputStream());
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(this.soket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println(this.soket.toString());
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Client: ");
                String clientMessage = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
                System.out.println(clientMessage);
            }
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void send(String message) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Send to: " + this.soket.toString());
            System.out.println(message);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(message);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Клиент:**

*MainClient.java*

```
public class MainClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("client");
        Client client = new Client(4444);
        client.Connection();
    }
}
```

*Client.java*

```
public class Client {

    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private InetAddress addr;
    private int port;

    public Client(int port) {
        try {
            addr = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            this.port = port;
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void Connection() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(addr, port);

            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            objectOutputStream.writeObject("Hello, " + this.toString());

            while (true) {
                String serverMessage = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();
                System.out.println(serverMessage);
                objectOutputStream.writeObject("OK : " + socket.toString());
            }

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Буду разбираться и с вашим и с нашим кодом)